# Query using two separate date coulmns in DynamoDB

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo db table with the following keys and attributes

1. id(primary key),
2. logged_at(sort key which is a date value. For Eg: 2020-10-27 06:30:00),
3. created_at(which is also a date value. For Eg: 2020-10-27 06:30:00)

How can I perform a similar query in dynamodb

```
SELECT id FROM test_db WHERE logged_at >= '2020-10-27 06:30:00
AND logged_at <= '2020-10-27 07:00:00' ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC LIMIT 10
```

I tried setting 'id' as primary key, 'logged_at' as sort key. I don't know how to sort using another key 'created_at' in descending. Please let me know if there is way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysql` on a DynamoDB question?

Comment: You can't, without `scan`. DynamoDB is regular database.

Comment: @brombeer, I have provided a mysql query in my question. What I expect is to perform a similar query in Dynamodb.

Comment: Is there some reason for filtering on one date but sorting on the other?

Comment: `<cynical>`If you are saying that DynamoDB cannot create the desired SQL, then stop using it.  This forum is littered with questions that boil down to "the framework is getting in the way".`</cynical>`

Comment: `WHERE` is for filtering; `ORDER BY` os for sorting.

Comment: Is this like sorting on last_name _and_ first_name?  That is like this in SQL:  `ORDER BY last_name, first_name` -- both columns in the `ORDER BY`, not the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 sort keys in DynamoDB, so which ever one you decide is the one that will sort the results.

DynamoDB is a Key Value store, where you must use the partition key to return the values, otherwise you lose your scalability and efficiency. You use case is the opposite, giving a range of two values you want the key returned.

You can use an index to help achieve this access pattern, but it's not optimal. If you have a need to use DynamoDB for other access patterns, then you can contemplate that. Otherwise, I would suggest evaluating a different database.